# Calling a function in a .js file from a .html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found many answers about this topic but it seems that they all do something I don't want. It should be a relatively easy question though.

In my html I have:

```
<button onclick= "myFunction();">Ptin Text</button>
```

while in my .js file I have:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

the .js file is included correctly at the end of my html but still the error I get is that the function **myFunction()** is not found. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance

**EDIT**: The function is defined inside a scope:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function myFunction() {
        console.log("foo");
    }
}
```

I understand that my html is not able to see within that scope, but why? Since the function is defined if the DOM is ready, it should be indeed able to see it.

Comment: Are you importing your script correctly? It works when I load your code in a fiddle

Comment: Working for me [here](https://jsbin.com/xorayawabe/edit?html,js,console,output). Is that all your code?

Comment: Can you please show the relevant part of the code (including the script tag)?

Comment: @J.Titus `onclick= "myFunction();"` is evaluated at the time when the click occurs. So it does not matter if the script is loaded after the button was created in the DOM. So either the script is not loaded at the time the button is clicked or `myFunction` is not defined in the global scope.

Comment: @t.niese indeed it is not defined in the global scope. But it makes sense for me putting its definition in a scope. If the document is not ready, I should not be able to access this function. Can you please explain me what's going no in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events that are defined inline using an attribute (`onclick= "myFunction();"`) can only access functions that are defined in the global scope.

A better idea would be to use `addEventListener` or `jQuery.on` to add event listeners.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   function myFunction() {
    console.log("foo");
   }

   $('button').on('click', myFunction);
}
```

If you have multiple `button` elements then you need to use an `id` or `class`.

Comment: thank you very much! very clear! sorry that my question moved many negative thoughts from other people but this is some basic thing I needed to understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Guess you included the js file wrong.

Try this:

```
<script src="your_javascript.js"></script>
```

Check the file by opening it in a new tab.

Answer (score -3):

You said you loaded in the JS file at the bottom of your page.  You need to load it in the top.  Or at least before the function call is made.  Otherwise it won't be able to find the function.

Comment: This is completely wrong... it doesn't matter because the function *will* be defined when you click... not matter where you load JS.